# Remove Value from a Tableview without wanting the answer from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I'm trying to perform a code when I remove a value from a tableView but this didn't work..

In fact I want to download from firebase the current value then subtract the value which is giving in an other box from firebase and the autoID is include in my tableView. So I've to download 2 informations from Firebase then perform the subtraction and send the new value to firebase before erase the ligne of my tableView.

I've currently this code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete{

        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser{

            // user is connect
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

            //soustraire les valeurs au total exp
            ref.child("Experience").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot) in

                if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:String]{
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


                    let ldg_day = value?["LDG_DAY"] as? String ?? "0"
                    let ldg_night = value?["LDG_NIGHT"] as? String ?? "0"
                    let apch_ifr = value?["APCH_IFR"] as? String ?? "0"


                    self.oldIntDayLdg = Int(ldg_day) ?? 0
                    /*self.intLdgNight = Int(ldg_night) ?? 0
                     self.intApchIfr = Int(apch_ifr) ?? 0*/

                    self.oldStringDayLdg = ldg_day
                    /*self.currentStringLdgNight = ldg_night
                     self.currentStringApchIfr = apch_ifr*/

                    print("getUserInfo : IntDay : \(self.oldIntDayLdg) & StringDay : \(self.oldStringDayLdg)")
                }
            }

        ref.child("flights").child(userID!).child(datas[indexPath.row].AutoId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot) in

            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:String]{
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


                    let this_flight_ldg_day = value?["LDG_DAY"] as? String ?? "0"
                    /*let ldg_night = value?["LDG_NIGHT"] as? String ?? "0"
                    let apch_ifr = value?["APCH_IFR"] as? String ?? "0"*/


                    self.thisIntDayLdg = Int(this_flight_ldg_day) ?? 0
                    /*self.intLdgNight = Int(ldg_night) ?? 0
                     self.intApchIfr = Int(apch_ifr) ?? 0*/

                    self.thisStringDayLdg = this_flight_ldg_day
                    /*self.currentStringLdgNight = ldg_night
                     self.currentStringApchIfr = apch_ifr*/
                    print("thisFlightInfo : IntDay : \(self.thisIntDayLdg) & StringDay : \(self.thisStringDayLdg)")
                }
            }
            print("Calcul : \(self.newIntDayLdg) = \(self.oldIntDayLdg) + \(self.thisIntDayLdg)")

            newIntDayLdg = oldIntDayLdg - thisIntDayLdg

            print("int result : \(self.newIntDayLdg)")

            newStringDayLdg = String(newIntDayLdg) ?? "00"

            print("String result : \(self.newStringDayLdg)")

            ref.child("Experience").child(userID!).updateChildValues(["LDG_DAY": self.newStringDayLdg//,
                                                                      /*"LDG_NIGHT": self.currentStringLdgNight,
                                                                      "APCH_IFR": self.currentStringApchIfr*/])

            ref.child("flights").child(userID!).child(datas[indexPath.row].AutoId).removeValue()

                    self.tableView.reloadData()



        }else{
            // si non connecté alors DECONNEXION !!!!
            fatalError("⛔️ error ...")
        }

        datas.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

But this one send me 0 each time and not the good value ...

`let ldg_day = value?["LDG_DAY"] as? String ?? "0"`give me 0

and

`let this_flight_ldg_day = value?["LDG_DAY"] as? String ?? "0"`give me also 0

moreover, with all my print I've got detected that the code print in first :

`print("Calcul : \(self.newIntDayLdg) = \(self.oldIntDayLdg) + \(self.thisIntDayLdg)")`

then

`print("String result : \(self.newStringDayLdg)")`

and only after the two print :

`print("getUserInfo : IntDay : \(self.oldIntDayLdg) & StringDay : \(self.oldStringDayLdg)")`

&

`print("thisFlightInfo : IntDay : \(self.thisIntDayLdg) & StringDay : \(self.thisStringDayLdg)")`

where is the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not very clear why are you converting `value` to `NSDictionary` when you already have it as dictionary `[String:String]` (if you didn't, you wouldn't need `as? String` conversion further down the road). But regardless, do you know that `value` contains `"LDG_DAY"` key?

Comment: For the order of print, it is because the closure of observeSingleEvent is executed async ; so, you jump immediately to print("Calcul") before the closure is executed, then you get the print in the closure.

Comment: @KirilS. If I convert a string to an Int it is because I need to subtract the value LDG_DAY from this Flight to Experience. I'm not sure that I can do this with a string ?!

Comment: @claude31 I totally understand that but how can I deal with that ? I need to receive my information before the tableview's line will be deleted ?

Comment: I understand why you convert string to int, I don't understand why you convert swift dictionary (`[String:String]`) into objective-c dictionary (`NSDictionary`)

Comment: @flyer74 I had a similar problem to have an alert before delete. I solved it by: dispatching in a queue, setting a semaphore, signal() the semaphore in the handler, and wait for the data being available before using the expected values (with semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)). Of course, need to take care in case the database is too long to return not to block ; but this occurs in a user thread, so everything will not be locked.

Comment: @claude31 Thanks for your help, I never saw this `signal()` did you have any example or tutorial because the apple developper doc is not expensive about this ...

Comment: I used several tutorials to learn : The best was probably this series https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2 ; I also used  https://priteshrnandgaonkar.github.io/concurrency-with-swift-3/